# how can i set my app's status bar to gray?

Tags: ios, statusbar

[iBooks's status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TAXm.png)
what the picture say, it's my want

How can I set my app's status bar to gray?
I only found the Default and `LightContent` in the `UIStatusBarStyle`.
How can iBooks do it?

Comment: Check with following link.
http://motzcod.es/post/110755300272/ios-tip-change-status-bar-icon-text-colors

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
```

in info.plist

Comment: can you explain that ?